# How do you distinguish between "remember" and "remind"?

Tags: traducción, verbos, polisemia

I used [Google](http://translate.google.com) to translate "remember" and "remind". Both came out to be `recordar`. Why is there no distinction made? You can only *remember* something by yourself, but you have to *remind* someone else of something. How can recordar represent two different actions?

Comment: Related and beautiful http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLbgNvjyS4I

Comment: Usually the verb `hacer` ("Recordé que tengo que devolver el libro" vs "La tarjeta de la biblioteca me hizo recordar que tengo que devolver el libro") makes the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Recordar* (and incidentally *acordar*) in Spanish works more like *recall* in English, than like *remember* or *remind*.  In English, *recall* can be used in both senses as *recordar*, and context determines the meaning:

> I don't remember his name / I don't recall his name. → *No recuerdo su nombre.*
>
> Remind me of his name / Recall to me his name. → *Recuérdeme su nombre.*

In both cases, the words *recordar* and *recall* are more about the act of pulling something from memory (similar to *remember*), than the act of communication (as in *remind*).  In the case of recalling to someone, it's the "to someone" part that implies the communication, not the verb itself.

---

**EDIT** *Remember* in English *can* also work this way, although it's rather rare, archaic or used for artistic purposes.  Consider the traditional English ballad made famous by Simon & Garfunkel as *Parsley, Sage, Rosemary and Thyme*:

> Are you going to Scarborough Fair?
>   Parsley, sage, rosemary, and thyme
>   *Remember me to one who lives there*
>   She once was a true love of mine

Comment: In short, _Recordar_ is a polysemic word that means both _To Remember_ and _To remind_.

Comment: @deStrangis And also "to wake up" (en muchos lugares)

Comment: @belisarius "Recuerde el alma dormida..."

Answer (score 2):

When Spanish people learn English we have the same problem, why do you use two verbs ? For us `recordar` is used in both cases.

Recordar means  `Traer a la memoria algo`.

Whether you want to share it with someone or not is up to you, because before reminding somebody to do something, you have to remember it ;).